# Protect aggainst Bruteforece with special Characters?

Tags: password-management, password-cracking

Is it possible that if I use special Characters in my password that it can't be Bruteforeced? Special Characters:  =!@$/^&( and so on

Comment: This question is extremely broad, try narrowing it down, what do you mean by special character? Like an Emoji? ASCII? UTF-8? Cyrillic/Russian/Hebrew/Thai characters?

Comment: @Azteca here is what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is likely to increase the time it takes to brute force said password, and with sufficient length and complexity, it is likely to be mathematically infeasible to brute force your password.